# Problemas com Navbar Collapse

Tags: collapse

Opa, tudo bem??? Estou com problemas ao fazer o navbar collapse, qdo clico no ícone não aparece o menu abaixo.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">O Rei do Bojo</a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>  


        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarMenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link nav-link" href="">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link nav-link" href="">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link nav-link" href="">Contato</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>

    </nav><!-- /navbar -->
</div>
```

E abaixo segue os links referências para boostrap no Body e os scripts do js.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, parece que você esqueceu de informar o identificador no `data-target="navbarMenu"`, como você esta usando ID fica assim `data-target="#navbarMenu"`.

Exemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">O Rei do Bojo</a>

              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>  


            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarMenu">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link nav-link" href="">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link nav-link" href="">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link nav-link" href="">Contato</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>

        </nav><!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém testei aqui e não deu certo.

Comment: Tem certeza? teste aqui e funcionou. Verifique se seus scripts estão sendo carregados corretamente, jquery e bootstrap CSS e JS,

Comment: Acabei de rodar esse script: if (window.jQuery == undefined)
    alert("Sem jQuery!"); e o retorno foi Sem jquery.

Comment: Ai esta seu problema seus links para os arquivos provavelmente estão errados. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> Link para o Jquery online.

Comment: Opa, coloquei o script fazendo a requisição on line aqui, e também não funcionou. Já estou maluco com isso kkkk ..... Segue abaixo:       <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script"></script>

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo funcionando...

Comment: Obrigado pela paciência e principalmente a dedicação em me ajudar!!! Funcionou, vlw!!!!!